# Validating a ISO 8601 date using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to validate a ISO 8601 date in javascript using moment.js

```
console.log(moment("2011-10-10T14:48:00", "YYYY-MM-DD", true).isValid())
```

It returns false. Where am I going wrong ? Is the date type format incorrect ?

**version:** Moment 2.5.1

Comment: **No** it is returning `true`.  http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/r42jg/49/

Comment: Hmm I'm using Moment 2.5.1 & I get false, Check the plnk - http://plnkr.co/edit/umqpqkqOgfRNeh5Gcafw?p=preview

Comment: thank you for the answers and for reverting the down vote and apologies for not going through the docs :)

Comment: FYI Basic ISO strings (e.g. 20111010) are not yet supported by moment, but are planned to be supported - https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2025

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not sure why Praveen's example works in jsfiddle, but the reason your sample doesn't work is because the format isn't YYYY-MM-DD. It includes the time as well, so it's considered invalid. If you try it without the time in the date, it returns true.

Try this instead:
`moment("2011-10-10T14:48:00", "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss", true).isValid()`

Answer (score 72):

To avoid using string pattern as a second argument, you can just call:

```
moment("2011-10-10T14:48:00", moment.ISO_8601).isValid() // true
moment("2016-10-13T08:35:47.510Z", moment.ISO_8601).isValid() // true
```

Comment: you can try `moment("1466113", moment.ISO_8601, true).isValid()` to see that avoiding string pattern does not work everywhere

Comment: @WhiteKnight According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Calendar_dates), YYYYMMDD is a valid ISO8601 date. If you only want to form with the hyphens, then you are actually only targeting a subset of ISO8601.

Answer (score 6):

Okay, I found it.

As per the [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/),

> As of version 2.3.0, you may specify a **`boolean`** for the last argument
>   to make Moment use strict parsing. Strict parsing requires that the
>   format and input match exactly

because you use strict operation, it returns **`false`**.  To overcome that use below code:

```
alert(moment("2011-10-10T14:48:00", "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss", true).isValid())
//This will return true
```

[**demo1**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/r42jg/52/)

If you *remove* the **`strict parsing`**,

```
alert(moment("2011-10-10T14:48:00", "YYYY-MM-DD").isValid())
//This will return true
```

[**demo2**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/r42jg/51/)

Comment: this returns true, i expect it to be false alert(moment("6205122", "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss, true").isValid())

Comment: There's a typo in the first jsfiddle:
 alert(moment("2011-10-10T14:48:00", "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss, true").isValid())

The double quote should be moved before the comma, before true.

Answer (score 1):

use this to match part of your date

```
console.log(moment("2011-10-10T14:48:00", "YYYY-MM-DD", false).isValid())
```

if you want exact format match then

```
console.log(moment("2011-10-10T14:48:00", "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss", true).isValid())
```